# Having problem in installation of Visual studio code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

After installation of VS code it only shows black screen,after every re-installation it opens but once close and reopen it showing only black screen.

Comment: screenshot, or something?

Comment: OS? Version? Screenshot? Any other programs that do that too?

Answer (score 0):

To solve black screen problem of vscode you need to follow these steps:

1. Right click on vscode icon.
2. Go to properties.
3. After target write " --disable-gpu"
4. click apply
5. Click ok

This is how your problem will be resolved.